# How to call __doPostBack in Callback function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap confirm box.. I want to call server side code in callback function.
I am trying using __doPostBack() but it not working through an error " __doPostBack is not defined"
here is the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function DoPost() {
        bootbox.confirm("Do you want to continue ??", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                __doPostBack();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
   }
   </script>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return DoPost();" />
```

So please suggest me how to call server side in callback function.
thank you.

Comment: `__doPostBack()` this function need to be defined/declare somewhere in your client side code which should initialized first before your bootbox.confirm call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following

```
__doPostBack('Button2,'');
```

You can also use `<%=ClientId%>` if the id changes at the browser.

Approach 2.

1. create a normal button `input type='button'`
2. Keep you `asp:button` hidden
3. Call the click event of `asp:button` in java-script
4. by using jquery `$(#buttonId).trigger("click")`

Answer (score 0):

minor syntax check:

```
__doPostBack('Button2', '');
```

You were missing the closing apostrophe after *Button2* :-)